# Why I'm getting status code 302 on query response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, http-status-code-302

Why I'm getting status code 302 on query response and how i can fix it?

[image: screenshot of query response and request headers]

**fetch method:**

```js
const grabApps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${spinnakerURL}/gate/applications`, {
    redirect: "manual"
  })
  return res.data || []
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer:
        {
            proxy:
                {
                    '/gate':
                        {
                            target: 'https://spinstatus.zenoss.io',
                            changeOrigin: true,
                            onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res, options) =>
                            {
                                proxyReq.setHeader('Origin', 'https://spinstatus.zenoss.io')
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what [status 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) means? You are being redirected. Seemingly to a login page. How can you fix it? Either by providing a valid credentials with your request or by following that redirect ...

Comment: Yes, I've checked it, but for me it is anyway unclear, because I'm logged in  redirected resource